# Pass environment variable to INSTALLDIR in msi

Tags: windows-installer, dsc

I am trying to write a PowerShell DSC configuration and have the following code:

```
Package RapidCRC
{
    Ensure = "Present"
    Path  = "C:\Repo\RapidCRC.Unicode.v0.3.27.x64\RapidCRC-Setup-0.3.27-x64.msi"
    Name = "RapidCRC (x64) 0.3.27"
    ProductId = "{27A6AB13-B66B-4AB8-BDA1-313477475F6A}"
    Arguments = 'INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Utilities\RapidCRC.Unicode" ALLUSERS=2 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=0'
}
```

I would like to pass C:\Program Files as an environment variable. I tried the following:

```
Arguments = 'INSTALLDIR="%ProgramFiles%\Utilities\RapidCRC.Unicode" ALLUSERS=2 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=0'

Arguments = 'INSTALLDIR="[ProgramFiles64Folder]Utilities\RapidCRC.Unicode" ALLUSERS=2 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=0'
```

but they do not work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your DSC setup? Push/pull?  Are you working with an x86 or x64 OS?

Comment: This is a push setup. All systems (the one I am pushing out of and the one receiving the configuration) are x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at PowerShell scripts. So, you can use `$env:ProgramFiles` in your DSC configuration script:

```
Package RapidCRC
{
    Ensure = "Present"
    Path  = "C:\Repo\RapidCRC.Unicode.v0.3.27.x64\RapidCRC-Setup-0.3.27-x64.msi"
    Name = "RapidCRC (x64) 0.3.27"
    ProductId = "{27A6AB13-B66B-4AB8-BDA1-313477475F6A}"
    Arguments = "INSTALLDIR=`"$($env:ProgramFiles)\Utilities\RapidCRC.Unicode`" ALLUSERS=2 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=0"
}
```

SIDE NOTE: Please pay attention to *backticks* used in `Argument` parameter.